# Gradle finished with non-zero exit value 255

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew, minecraft-forge

I am very new to Java coding and I decided to modify Minecraft as a fun project following a tutorial. When I went to run the Minecraft client from the debug menu, I received:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':runClient'.
> Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-17.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 255

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

I've checked my code multiple times and there doesn't seem to be any differences between mine and the tutorial that I'm following. The tutorial was posted this year in January if that helps. I've looked for solutions for this problem but none were overly helpful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, non-zero exit code means an irregular exit.
You should check out `latest.log` or `debug.log` in the running directory to inspect what was happened. They contain a crash report which helps identify your problem.